# Determining the Best Location Based on Distances Between Two DataFrames in R

Tags: r

I'm working on an R project involving the analysis of two dataFrames: `df` and `df`2. The `df`  contains information about properties grouped into clusters, while df2 contains geographical coordinates of points of interest. My goal is to determine the best location to choose based on the distances between properties within each cluster in `df` and all points in `df2`. Please, use `distm` function. For example, for cluster 1 the best point is `id = 3`, for cluster 2 is `id = 1`, and so. This is idea

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), 
               Longitude = c(-46.585970687, -51.037570982, -49.656622, -46.730269, 
                             -49.255356686, -48.982128819, -50.177308), 
               Latitude = c(-23.611080198, -21.659062133, -21.24666, -21.948196, 
                            -22.880896112, -22.429487865, -21.578706), 
               Cluster = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))

  ID Longitude  Latitude Cluster
1  A -46.58597 -23.61108       1
2  B -51.03757 -21.65906       1
3  C -49.65662 -21.24666       1
4  D -46.73027 -21.94820       2
5  E -49.25536 -22.88090       2
6  F -48.98213 -22.42949       2
7  G -50.17731 -21.57871       2


df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Longitude = c(-52.810111532, 
                                                                   -52.810111532, -52.710111532, -52.710111532, -52.710111532, -52.610111532, 
                                                                   -52.610111532, -52.610111532), Latitude = c(-22.479655795, -22.579655795, 
                                                                                                               -22.379655795, -22.479655795, -22.579655795, -22.279655795, -22.379655795, 
                                                                                                               -22.479655795)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"))

     id Longitude Latitude
  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     -52.8    -22.5
2     2     -52.8    -22.6
3     3     -52.7    -22.4
4     4     -52.7    -22.5
5     5     -52.7    -22.6
6     6     -52.6    -22.3
7     7     -52.6    -22.4
8     8     -52.6    -22.5
```

Comment: So you'd like to select a closest cluster from `df` (1 or 2 in this example) for every POI in `df2` ? How do you define "closeness", would it be a distance to cluster centroid, distance to nearest cluster point or something else? Or you want to select a closest point  from `df` (ID col, values A ... G) for every POI in `df2` ?